# How can I wait for all executors inside Jenkinsfile's "parallel" block?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins and configuring its scripts, so please forgive me if I say anything stupid.

I have a scripted Jenkins pipeline which redistributes building of the codebase to multiple nodes, implemented using a `node` block wrapped with `parallel` block. Now, the catch is that after the building, I would like to do a certain action with files that were just built, on one of the nodes that was building the code - but only after all of the nodes are done. Essentially, what I would like to have is something similar to [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)), but between Jenkins' nodes.

Simplified, my Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
def buildConf = ["debug", "release"]

parallel buildConf.collectEntries { conf ->
    [ conf, {
        node {
            sh "./checkout_and_build.sh"

            // and here I need a barrier
            if (conf == "debug") {
                // I cannot do this outside this node block,
                // because execution may be redirected to a node
                // that doesn't have my files checked out and built
                sh "./post_build.sh"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a global counter which counts the number of completed tasks, you need to instruct each task that have post job to wait until the counter is equal to the total number of tasks, first then you can do the post task parts. Like this:

```
def buildConf = ["debug", "release"]
def doneCounter = 0

parallel buildConf.collectEntries { conf ->
    [ conf, {
        node {
            sh "./checkout_and_build.sh"

            doneCounter++
            // and here I need a barrier
            if (conf == "debug") {
                waitUntil { doneCounter == buildConf.size() }
                // I cannot do this outside this node block,
                // because execution may be redirected to a node
                // that doesn't have my files checked out and built
                sh "./post_build.sh"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Please note, each task that has post task parts will block the executor until all other parallell tasks are done and the post part can be executed. If you have loads of executors or the tasks are fairly short, then this is probably not a problem. But if you have few executors it could lead to congestion. If you have less or equal number of executors than the total number of parallell tasks which need post work, then you can run into a deadlock!